# why is the standard error so high for my probit model

Tags: regression, machine-learning, binary-data, probit, statsmodels

I have created two probit models, and even though p values are significant and sample spaces are large- 10000 samples in both- standard errors seem to be about 6.27e. What could be the reason for that?

Here are the results:

````
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                 9413
Model:                         Probit   Df Residuals:                     9412
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            0
Date:                Sat, 30 Jan 2021   Pseudo R-squ.:                 0.04258
Time:                        10:41:23   Log-Likelihood:                -6067.9
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -6337.8
Covariance Type:            nonrobust   LLR p-value:                       nan
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x1             0.0018   6.27e-05     28.368      0.000       0.002       0.002
==============================================================================```

```                          Probit Regression Results                           
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                 9888
Model:                         Probit   Df Residuals:                     9887
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            0
Date:                Sat, 30 Jan 2021   Pseudo R-squ.:                 0.03962
Time:                        13:33:44   Log-Likelihood:                -6225.9
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -6482.7
Covariance Type:            nonrobust   LLR p-value:                       nan
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x1             0.0020   6.18e-05     32.747      0.000       0.002       0.002
==============================================================================
````

Comment: (Which software is this?) You seem to have only one predictor, and likelihood ratio test against null model is highly significant (for some reason p-value is printed as `nan` which is strange). Look at (and show us ) plots of Y versus x, and probably the reason will show itself (some jittering of Y, and added smooth might give a better plot).

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen this is clearly created with statsmodels, so it is impossible to plot. P-value seems nan, but we can see that coefficient is correlated from ```P>|z``` . However, I am not sure why standard error is so significant. Might it be because there is only one predictor?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I used statsmodels, so I cannot plot.

Comment: If it is really impossible to plot with statsmodels (I find that hard to believe), then do the plotting outside statsmodels.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: you should include a constant to get any meaningful results. This is the Probit equivalent of regression through zero which we almost never want.

Comment: Because you wrote "seem to be about 6.27e," I need to ask--and do not intend any offense--whether you understand that `6.27e-05` means $6.27\times 10^{-5}$?